# How to insert in a nested hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary, nested, hashmap

I have a nested hashmap like

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Obzect>> map1= new HashMap<>();
```

The first map key will be `object.getId` and key of second map can be "p1","p2" or such based on some conditions.
I am trying to insert into a hashmap without creating an instance for second map.

```
map1.put(object.getId,map1.get(object.getId).put("p1",object));
```

I am getting error message

```
Required Type: hashmap
Provided Type: object
```

How to correct this?

Comment: if the nested map is already present in the first map, then this should suffice ```map1.get(object.getId).put("p1",object)```. You dont need to fiddle with the first map.

Comment: What is `Obzect`? Can you provide more details about what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Obzect is object. Its actually an instance of a model. i dont know why if i write <object> it disappears. So i made a typo.

Comment: May be `guava cache` is a better choice. You can provide more details about what do you want to do. `map1.get(object.getId).put("p1", object)` @UjjwalKuikel ?

Comment: Hi, The issue has been solved. Thanks for the input anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    record Obzect(String getId) {}
    Obzect object = new Obzect("id");

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Obzect>> map1= new HashMap<>();
    map1.computeIfAbsent(object.getId, k -> new HashMap<>()).put("p1", object);

    System.out.println(map1);
}
```

output:

```
{id={p1=Obzect[getId=id]}}
```